# how to execute functions (with parameter )in parallel using AsyncTask in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am writing an Android app in which I made functions for each task to execute,
but at some point I wanted to have 3 functions that should start the execution in parallel. I know about AsyncTask class (it can execute task in parallel) but I am not sure how to implement it in my code. Below is my code design....(raw code)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        function101();
        function103(String ef);  // this 2 function should execute in parallel

    }

    private void function101(){
        // some code
    }

    private void function102(String ab, int cd){

        function101();

        function103( String ef);   // i want this 2 function should execute in parallel

    }

    private void function103(String ef){
        // some code
    }

    private void function104(){

        function101();
        function102(String ab, int cd);
        function103(String ef);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have 2 or more instance of Asynctask *depending on your needs.*

```
public void function101(){
        new AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>(){

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                // code here

                return null;
            }

        }.execute();
 }
```

And your other function *Although it is should be called as method*

```
public void function103(String ef){
         new AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>(){

             @Override
             protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                  // code here

                  return null;
             }

         }.execute();
}
```